Images uploded but not saved in database
When users upload images in application, they are successfully saved to the server's file system within a folder named "Images". However, despite the successful file storage, encountering an issue where the images are not being saved in the database. Notably, this problem is isolated to your live environment running on IIS; my local development environment operates without this issue.
public async Task<ApprovalPurchaseRequest?> ApproveRequestWithinvoice(int? id, int? decisionNumber, IFormFileCollection? image)
{
   var approvalRequest = await _context.ApprovalPurchaseRequests.FindAsync(id);
   var purchaseRequest = await _context.PurchaseRequests.FindAsync(approvalRequest?.RequestId);


   if (_User.IsInRole("Employee Admin"))
   {
       string folder = "Images";
       string serverFolderPath = Path.Combine(webHost.WebRootPath, folder);
       if (image != null && image.Count > 0)
       {

           foreach (var item in image)
           {
               if (!Directory.Exists(serverFolderPath))
               {
                   Directory.CreateDirectory(serverFolderPath);
               }

               string extension = Path.GetExtension(item.FileName);
               string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + extension;
               string filePath = Path.Combine(serverFolderPath, fileName);

               using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
               {
                   await item.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
               }

               string relativeFilePath = "/Images/" + fileName;

               Image _image = new()
               {
                   ImagePath = relativeFilePath,
                   IdPurchaseRequest = purchaseRequest!.IdPurchaseRequest,
                   ItIsInvoise = true,
               };

               _context.Add(_image);
               await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
           }

       }

   }

   return approvalRequest;

}


you are only storing a path there.  I would avoid using the user-submitted file extension here.   Case/switch specific extensions and write them yourself.

can you clarify the problem a bit?  Is it just that the images aren't showing when linked to?  You may need to set app.UseStaticFiles() in program.cs.   You should also consider whether you want direct public access to those files.  (You can alternatively store these where only your code can reach them and then create an endpoint which can check for user authorization before returning File.

some time the images path save in database but some time dont save it in database , but all the time the images saved in images path in my server

I would write the record to the database first.  Use the record's UID/primary key as the filename.  (if you can get _image's id property you'll know the db save happened... you might also confirm the path was written while debugging this) Case/switch the extension so you can explicitly set that (don't rely on untrusted user-input).  After that save the file using same...

This should be the IIS worker process does not have rights to read/write files, please make sure application pool identity have read/write permissions to that path.
You can refer to below link about how to configure the application pool identity.
Application Pool Identities.

some time the images path save in database but some time dont save it in database , but all the time the images saved in images path in my server

Do you get any error messages? Please check if there are any related error messages in Event Viewer.
